# How to solve an error while cloning a private repository

Tags: github

I have a repository which is private. Before, I was able to clone it from my terminal by giving the username and password. Few days back I got a mail from GitHub to enable 2FA in my account. I did but now I see my account password doesn't seem to work when I give my  password in my terminal. I use Google Authenticator as my TOTP app and I also tried giving that password but still it says authentication failure. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "Personal Access Token" (PAT). 
In order to generate one, go to your [GitHub settings](https://github.com/settings) and click on the category called "Developer settings". In that section, go to [personal tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

There you can generate a new access token (make surer to check `repo`). When you clone your repository, use this token **instead of your password**. Now you should be able to clone it.

You can read more about this process here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: You don't need to join the developer program to get developer settings or create PATs.  A PAT is the right answer here, though.

Comment: @bk2204 My bad. Corrected the answer. Thanks!